# Visual Studio 2019 cannot connect to SQL Server database - The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, connection

This started happening to me in the past week or so. I've searched the web and tried various suggested solutions, nothing has worked so far. I didn't change my password during this time period. I tried rebooting my laptop, reconnecting to the network (VPN), running ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew, all to no avail.

I have no problem connecting to the SQL server database running on my local machine, it's when I try to connect to a database running on a network server that this issue comes up. Outside of VS, I can connect to the network database from Management Studio without any issue.

In SQL Server Object Explorer, I tried to add a new SQL Server (my local database server appears in the list), I got the error message "The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server)"

Any helpful insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might try using a search engine for your error message. There are literally thousands of examples of solving this very issue...the first one for me is from SO.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - that was the first thing I did. Most examples are related to unable to connect to db from Management Studio, which is not an issue for me. My problem is Visual Studio cannot connect to the db.

Comment: The issue is the same; DBATools and Test-dbaspn are your friend here